# Need For -Each Logic Based on variable value derived without node/root in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Please help in below  "for-each" logic written to loop based on variable value derived in XSL 1.0. Note:  Recursive method i.e template within a template cannot be called in our scenario.

Snippet code Scenario which is not working attached below

```
<xsl:variable name="finalcount">
     <xsl:value-of select="floor($CountofEmp)"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="$finalcount">     
        do something
</xsl:for-each>
```

Required output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing an example of the XML input and an executable XSLT.

Comment: If you have a constraint that there are XSLT constructs (like recursive templates) that you cannot use, then you need to tell us more about these constraints. Coding with one hand tied behind your back is one thing, but doing it blindfold (ie. when you don't know the exact nature of the constraints, or their reasoning) gets... difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely clear. If - as it seems - you want to produce a sequence of numbers from 1 to some value, then you need to call a recursive named template - for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="count-up">
        <xsl:with-param name="n" select="6"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="count-up">
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:if test="$n > 0">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="count-up">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:value-of select="$n"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Note that there is no "template within a template" here.

Answer (score 0):

```
  This works as long as final count is not massive.  
  Too bad you can't use recursion.  But, recursion is limited.
  So, if final count is too big, you'll have a problem with recursion.
  
  
  <!--  Make a variable to use with your count. -->    
  <xsl:variable name="items">
    <xsl:element name="i"/>
    <xsl:element name="i"/>
    <xsl:element name="i"/>
    <xsl:element name="i"/>
    <xsl:element name="i"/>
    <xsl:element name="i"/>
    <xsl:element name="i"/>
    <xsl:element name="i"/>
    <xsl:element name="i"/>
    <xsl:element name="i"/>
    <xsl:element name="i"/>
    <xsl:element name="i"/>
    <xsl:element name="i"/>
    <xsl:element name="i"/>
    <xsl:element name="i"/>
    <!--  Add more i elements than the possible max size of your count variable. -->
  </xsl:variable>  

  <!-- Convert to node set using your own prefix.  msxml may not work for you. -->
  <xsl:variable name="iList" select="msxml:node-set($items)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="finalcount">
    <xsl:value-of select="6"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$iList/i[position() &lt;= $finalcount]">   
       <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
       <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Alternatively,
       you could replace iList with something that already exists 
       in the xml that your XSLT is running against as long as it
       has more elements than finalCount.  What you really need is
       something to count. -->
```

Comment: In what way "recursion is limited"?

Comment: Using the recursive template that michael.hor257k created in this post, I got a "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException" when I set n to 25,000 in the count-up template.  It did work for 20,000 which I wasn't expecting.  The algorithm is very efficient.  And for practical purposes probably sufficient.  I've gotten stack overflow errors for many less iterations.  It depends on the context I guess; how much is already on the stack and what is going on the stack.  I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: This non recursive algorithm seems to run fairly well for large numbers:  100000 (Stylesheet execution time: 729.9 ms) 1000000  (Stylesheet execution time: 8252 ms)  10000000   (Stylesheet execution time: 72789 ms)

Comment: Are you seriously contemplating putting a "bank" of 100k or more nodes in your stylesheet to avoid recursion?

Comment: Hi michael.hor257k,  The idea is to put 100 i elements in variable1.  Then create variable2 by doing a copy-of variable1 100 times.  Then create variable3 by doing a copy-of variable2 10 times.  That's 100,000.  I would do this, if I needed it.  Probably stash it at the bottom out of the way...  I did 10,000,000 for a test.  That said, this solution answers the question of how to do it without recursion or if recursion is causing a stack overflow.  Unlikely I would ever need it.  :)  Cheers!

Comment: I have a feeling we'll find out that OP's request to avoid recursion is not a legitimate one (if we ever find out the reason). As for SO, I suspect a more elegant method could be found to reduce the stack size, but I am not going to spend time on it now.